# Avoid forcing to return Image (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
  struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    imageWithCircle(sfsymbol: "shared.with.you", width: 30, height: 30)
           
  }
func imageWithCircle(sfsymbol: String, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> Image {
    return Image(systemName: sfsymbol)
        .frame(width: width, height: height)
        .background(
            Circle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(width: width + 5, height: height + 5)
        )
}

  }
```

I'm receiving this error "Cannot convert return expression of type 'some View' to return type 'Image'" "Insert as! Image".

I have only one return view of Image and return as Image, why would the compiler ask me to force return type?

Answer (score 3):

If you return only `Image`, the error would not occur.

However, you are trying to return an `Image` with `Modifiers`, so this should be a `some View` type instead of Image.

Try this:

```
func imageWithCircle(sfsymbol: String, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> some View {}
```